# Defining function and printing in c

Tags: c, compiler-errors, definition

I am trying to define predefined function and it is giving me error... what is wrong with below prog. somebody told me that I can define predefined function. I know this is not correct but still I am posting... if somebody have .....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define scanf "%s abc";

int main()
 {
  printf(scanf,scanf); 
   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: You should probably start with a tutorial or book on c, rather than "somebody" telling you random words.

Comment: you need to `#undef scanf` first too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should delete the semicolon in the line #define

Answer (score 6):

This

```
printf(scanf, scanf);
```

Expands to this

```
printf("%s abc"; , "%s abc";);
```

Obviously it won't compile with those semicolons inside the function call. Drop the semicolon in the macro definition and the function call will turn into

```
printf("%s abc" , "%s abc");
```

Which might compile and print `%s abc abc`. Or it might do something completely different, because it iss undefined behavior as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53881194/defining-function-and-printing-in-c/53881996#53881996) explains in better detail.

This aside, that macro usage is very nonsensical and misleading, so I would strongly recommend against it. Don't use macros to redefine valid identifiers such as `scanf` because if someone else tries to read the code, they won't understand it as the things they know suddenly don't work that way anymore.

Comment: It's UB so it doesn't have to compile or print anything.

Comment: Good catch, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the C standard says regarding defining standard library identifiers as macros:

C17 7.1.3/1 emphasis mine:

> - **Each identifier** with file scope listed in any of the following subclauses (including the
>     future library directions) **is reserved for use as a macro name** and as an identifier with
>     file scope in the same name space **if any of its associated headers is included**.

C17 7.1.3/2 emphasis mine:

> No other identifiers are reserved. **If the program** declares or defines an identifier in a
>   context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or **defines a reserved
>   identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.**

This means that anything can happen and `#include <stdio.h>` followed by `#define scanf` is to be regarded as a bug.